# In react js How to fetch the variable which is in inside a function in class coponent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to fetch the variable which is inside a function in class component. This is my function I want to fetch the "newArray" variable in class component.

```
handleChanges(event) { 
          this.setState({value: event.target.value}); 
          console.log("value",event.target.value);
         
          let values=['OurStory','HowItWorks','Blog','Login','BeaParopakari'];
          console.log("values",values);
          let url =
          "http://localhost:49590/api/Authenticate/Translate?values=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
          let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
          const accessToken = user;
          console.log(accessToken);
          fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json",
              Accept: "application/json",
              Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Request-Headers "
            }
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
             this.setState({    
               Details: data
             });
            console.log("Filter", data);
            const longArray = data;
            const size = 1;
            
            const newArray = new Array(Math.ceil(longArray.length / size)).fill("")
                .map(function() { return this.splice(0, size) }, longArray.slice());

               

                console.log(this.state.newArray);
                const trans = "Vijayaasri";
              
          });
```

I tried it in state but it didn't work.

```
{this.state.newArray.map(s=>s.result)}
```

I use map function to fetch.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipxcq.png)

This newArray value I need to print in page. Please share your knowledge. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: `newArray` should be a state `this.state.newArray` and use `this.setState({newArray: newValue})` to assign it a new array. You have it correct for other variables but you've used `const newArray` instead.

Comment: I try it. But it didn't work

Comment: Any Idea you people having. To get the variable value which is inside a function in class component.